# Woocommerce Price Filter Php text wraps

Tags: php, woocommerce

On my woocommerce site I added the woocommerce price filter in the sidebar of the store. The problem is that the price is placed next to the Filter button and then the text wraps. How can I move the text above the button? Do I have to change the php code of the price filter?
I inspected the page with google chrome and I saw that moving a div further up I solved the problem, but how do I apply it?

look at the sidebar [link](https://laviadeicristalli.it/negozio/)

this is the php file

```
class WC_Widget_Price_Filter extends WC_Widget {

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_price_filter';
    $this->widget_description = __( 'Display a slider to filter products in your store by price.', 'woocommerce' );
    $this->widget_id          = 'woocommerce_price_filter';
    $this->widget_name        = __( 'Filter Products by Price', 'woocommerce' );
    $this->settings           = array(
        'title'  => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'std'   => __( 'Filter by price', 'woocommerce' ),
            'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    );
    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    wp_register_script( 'accounting', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/accounting/accounting' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0.4.2' );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-jquery-ui-touchpunch', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery-ui-touch-punch' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery-ui-slider' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-price-slider', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/frontend/price-slider' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery-ui-slider', 'wc-jquery-ui-touchpunch', 'accounting' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'wc-price-slider', 'woocommerce_price_slider_params', array(
        'currency_format_num_decimals' => 0,
        'currency_format_symbol'       => get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(),
        'currency_format_decimal_sep'  => esc_attr( wc_get_price_decimal_separator() ),
        'currency_format_thousand_sep' => esc_attr( wc_get_price_thousand_separator() ),
        'currency_format'              => esc_attr( str_replace( array( '%1$s', '%2$s' ), array( '%s', '%v' ), get_woocommerce_price_format() ) ),
    ) );

    if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-price-slider' );
    }

    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Output widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    global $wp;

    if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! wc()->query->get_main_query()->post_count ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-price-slider' );

    // Find min and max price in current result set.
    $prices = $this->get_filtered_price();
    $min    = floor( $prices->min_price );
    $max    = ceil( $prices->max_price );

    if ( $min === $max ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

    if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
        $form_action = remove_query_arg( array( 'page', 'paged', 'product-page' ), add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
    } else {
        $form_action = preg_replace( '%\/page/[0-9]+%', '', home_url( trailingslashit( $wp->request ) ) );
    }

    $min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['min_price'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min );
    $max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['max_price'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max );

    echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
        <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
            <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div class="price_slider_amount">
                <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="' . esc_attr( $min_price ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Min price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="' . esc_attr( $max_price ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                <button type="submit" class="button">' . esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
                <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
                    ' . esc_html__( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
                </div>
                ' . wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_price', 'max_price' ), '', true ) . '
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>';

    $this->widget_end( $args );
}

/**
 * Get filtered min price for current products.
 * @return int
 */
protected function get_filtered_price() {
    global $wpdb;

    $args       = wc()->query->get_main_query()->query_vars;
    $tax_query  = isset( $args['tax_query'] ) ? $args['tax_query'] : array();
    $meta_query = isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ? $args['meta_query'] : array();

    if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && ! empty( $args['term'] ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
            'terms'    => array( $args['term'] ),
            'field'    => 'slug',
        );
    }

    foreach ( $meta_query + $tax_query as $key => $query ) {
        if ( ! empty( $query['price_filter'] ) || ! empty( $query['rating_filter'] ) ) {
            unset( $meta_query[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query );
    $tax_query  = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );

    $meta_query_sql = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
    $tax_query_sql  = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

    $sql  = "SELECT min( FLOOR( price_meta.meta_value ) ) as min_price, max( CEILING( price_meta.meta_value ) ) as max_price FROM {$wpdb->posts} ";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as price_meta ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = price_meta.post_id " . $tax_query_sql['join'] . $meta_query_sql['join'];
    $sql .= "   WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_post_type', array( 'product' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
                AND price_meta.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_meta_keys', array( '_price' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND price_meta.meta_value > '' ";
    $sql .= $tax_query_sql['where'] . $meta_query_sql['where'];

    if ( $search = WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql() ) {
        $sql .= ' AND ' . $search;
    }

    return $wpdb->get_row( $sql );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the form code (widget function -> below $max_price variable) with this:

```
echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
    <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
        <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div class="price_slider_amount">
            <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="' . esc_attr( $min_price ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Min price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
            <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="' . esc_attr( $max_price ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
            <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
                ' . esc_html__( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
            </div>
            ' . wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_price', 'max_price' ), '', true ) . '
            <button type="submit" class="button">' . esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>';
```